# Oracle : Selecting multiple columns with avg function

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

I am trying to display the average values of each player on a row by row basis with the player name 
I have looked throughout the oracle docs and previous question asked by other people on stack overflow. I have only come across on how to select average value group by their record id and how to select avg using subquery

For an example,
What i found is to get the average by each row by

```
select round(avg(g1+g2+g3+g4)) as "Average Score" from ch_user group by playerid;
```

Do note that i didnt display my PlayerID shown in the picture . 
[image]

If i were to select player and avg , it will give me ORA-01427. 
 I have tried

`select player, (select round(avg(g1+g2+g3+g4)) from ch_user group by playerid) as "Average Score" from ch_user;`

But its prompting the error ORA-01427. 
single-row subquery returns more than one row.

Thank you in advance

**UPDATED**

I have already found the solution to the problem and i am able to implement it to my query based on @Boneist answer.

However, i find the query long, is there by any chance i could simplify the query ?

My query is

```
select first_name || ' ' || last_name as Player,game_1 as G1 , game_2 as g2 ,
game_3 as g3, game_4 as G4,total_score as "Total Tournament Score",
round(avg(game_1+game_2+game_3+game_4)) as "Average Score" from ch_user
group by playerid, first_name,last_name,game_1,game_2,game_3,game_4,total_score;
```

[image]

Comment: `select MAX(PLAYER), round(avg(g1+g2+g3+g4)) as "Average Score" from ch_user group by playerid; ` -- hope that playerid is primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've overthought this... all you need to do is add `player` into the select list in your first query and add `player` into the group by:

```
select player,
       round(avg(g1 + g2 + g3 + g4)) as "Average Score"
from   ch_user
group by playerid, player;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to group the data by player_id, but display player name and average. Check if this helps.

```
select player_name,round(avg(g1+g2+g3+g4)) "Average"
from ch_user
group by player_id,player_name;
```